# Screenshot error with import linux command on enlightenment 17

Tags: linux, terminal, screenshot, enlightenment

I have installed enlightenment 17 on a debian 8 Jessie and I have issues about doing screenshot with import command.

Once I type "`import test.png`" from a terminal, and after selecting the area with mouse (for example, a mixed area of desktop and terminal at first plane), I get only a dark image of terminal.

I tried with and without "screenshot" module activation but I get the same problem.

Nothing appears in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.

I tried also with :

```
$ xwd -root > myscreen.xwd 
$ convert myscreen.xwd myscreen.png
```

and I get a dark image of terminology too. It seems that it has captured an old image (just preceding the import command) of Desktop.

Has someone already got this kind of problem on e17 for doing a screenshot ?

Thanks

Comment: Try it with the graphicsmagick package installed : `gm import screenshot.jpg`.

Comment: Do you have compositing on? Try to disable it. Found this advice [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=19649).

Comment: You may also try [the -screen option](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#screen).

Comment: @harrymc Thanks, it works with "gm import" command. Could you tell me the difference between "gm import" and "import" command. Are both included in ImageMagick package ( it seems "import" is included into ImageMagick package and "gm" into "GraphicsMagick" package) ?

Comment: I put the information in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having problems with the ImageMagick package, you can try the GraphicsMagick package, where the syntax will be :

```
gm import screenshot.jpg
```

Both graphical packages are completely independent, actually competitors.
From the [GraphicsMagick website](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/) :

> GraphicsMagick is originally derived from ImageMagick 5.5.2 as of
>   November 2002 but has been completely independent of the ImageMagick
>   project since then. Since the fork from ImageMagick many improvements
>   have been made by many authors using an open development model but
>   without breaking the API or utilities operation.

In general, I prefer GraphicsMagick over ImageMagick, since I find the former
to be more efficient and better programmed.